# HTML - text position like squared number

Tags: html, css, symbols

As I found [this](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/punctuation/superscript-two/) for squared symbol numbers.

Is it maybe possible to have some [text] like number two is presented in example?

Like here if you put:

```
&#178;
```

in HTML code you got:   2**²**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Latin_and_Greek_tables, but the “Superscript minuscules” don’t cover _all_ letters, `q` for example is missing.

Comment: But https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup also exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put those characters after the text you want or your can use `<sup>` tag around 2.

```html
2&#178;

2<sup>2</sup>
```

Comment: That could be a question for an interview! Totally forget about it, since learned CSS tried to do everyting with styles. CSS distorts perception )

Answer (score 1):

This is called **Superscript** and actually there is a special HTML element just for this task: `<sup>`

You simply need to wrap your desired text inside `<sup></sup>`

Here's an example:

```html
<span>my<sup>text</sup></span>
```